# Use wildcard in when groups statements

Tags: ansible

I would like to execute a task only when host is in group `*beat`, like this.

```yaml
when:
  - (groups['*beat'] is defined and inventory_hostname in groups['*beat'])
```

Which does not work. The task is skipped all the time.

Anyone has an idea how I can achive the desired behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the problem at hand the other way around could maybe help: instead of trying to find if the current host you are looping on is indeed in a specific group pattern, you could list the groups that the host is in, [with the variable `group_names`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html), and then [`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#select) only the groups that match your pattern.
From there on, if the list is empty, then it means your host is not in a group respecting the pattern.

Given the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    localhost:

  vars:
    ansible_connection: local

  children:
    heartbeat:
      hosts:
        rate:
        diastole:
        systole:
      
    filebeat:
      hosts:
        syslog:
        file:
        stdout:

    fox:
      hosts:
        brown:
        jump:
        over:
        lazy:
        dog:
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no  
        
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "I am in a group named *beat"
      when: 
        - group_names | select('match', '^(.*)beat$') | list | length > 0
```

It gives the output:

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
ok: [rate] => {
    "msg": "I am in a group named *beat"
}
ok: [diastole] => {
    "msg": "I am in a group named *beat"
}
ok: [systole] => {
    "msg": "I am in a group named *beat"
}
ok: [syslog] => {
    "msg": "I am in a group named *beat"
}
ok: [file] => {
    "msg": "I am in a group named *beat"
}
ok: [stdout] => {
    "msg": "I am in a group named *beat"
}
skipping: [brown]
skipping: [jump]
skipping: [over]
skipping: [lazy]
skipping: [dog]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
brown                      : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
diastole                   : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
dog                        : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
file                       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
jump                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
lazy                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
over                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
rate                       : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
stdout                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
syslog                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
systole                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```